# Laravel: many-to-many with shared table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have `Locations` model which hasMany `Employees` -- similarly `Employees` belongsTo `Locations`

This is nice and works well, but then I looked at adding `PhoneNumbers`. **Either** a `Location` or an `Employee` could have a phone number (office numbers versus personal numbers)

Logically:

`Locations` hasMany `PhoneNumbers` (multiple office lines)
and
`Employees` hasMany `PhoneNumbers` (home / cell ?)

However when you create a hasMany relationship like this in Laravel it adds a field to the `PhoneNumbers` table. So we now have **two** fields: `location_id` and `employee_id`

I can get this to work if I make `location_id` and `employee_id` nullable, like so:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
| id |    number    | location_id | employee_id |
+----+--------------+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | 800-555-0123 |      1      |     null    |
|  2 | 800-555-0124 |      1      |     null    |
|  3 | 800-555-0125 |      1      |     null    |
|  4 | 859-555-0199 |     null    |       1     |
                     ...
```

However this doesn't scale very well if I add new entities that can possess phone numbers (customers? job applicants? suppliers?)

**How can I create multiple separate many-to-many relationships with the same secondary table?**

**Note:** In this example I could just create a `phone_number` field on each individual tables (`locations.phone_number`, `employees.phone_number`, etc) however I wish to avoid this for two reasons:

1. Data integrity (if all phone numbers are in one common table it's easy to verify duplicate phone numbers are not entered)
2. Binding to more complex models (replace `PhoneNumber` with `Image` and now you have a lot more data to deal with)

Comment: Everything is documented, why bother write a question.

Comment: Because if you don't know the proper terminology then documentation does you no good. I could spend all day Googling "many to many relationship with different tables" and I'd never find the word "polymorphic"

Comment: __Polymorphic relations allow a model to belong to more than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a photo model that belongs to either a staff model or an order model.__  Straight from documentation... I am just trying to point out that this is documented very well, I don't want to be rude or anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for Laravel's polymorphic relationship. Instead of creating a new field for each related table, you have two fields: related id and related type.

On both your Location and Employee model, add the following relationship:

```
public function phones()
{
    return $this->morphMany('PhoneNumber', 'phonable');
}
```

On your PhoneNumber model, add the following relationship:

```
public function phonable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

On your phone_numbers table, add two new fields: phonable_type and phonable_id. In a migration, these fields are added with the `morphs()` method: `$table->morphs('phonable');`

Once everything is setup, your data would look like this:

```
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| id |    number    | phonable_id | phonable_type |
+----+--------------+-------------+---------------+
|  1 | 800-555-0123 |      1      |    Location   |
|  2 | 800-555-0124 |      1      |    Location   |
|  3 | 800-555-0125 |      1      |    Location   |
|  4 | 859-555-0199 |      1      |    Employee   |
                     ...
```

With this setup, you can make any model you want `phonable` just by adding a `morphOne()` or `morphMany()` relationship to it.

Additionally, the relationship attributes will generate the correct model related to the type.  Given the data above:

```
var_dump(PhoneNumber::find(1)->phonable); // will dump Location object
var_dump(PhoneNumber::find(4)->phonable); // will dump Employee object
```

The documentation on polymorphic relationships can be found [here (4.2)](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations) or [here (5.0)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#polymorphic-relations).