# Laravel: Polymorphic many-to-one (opposed to one-to-many)

Tags: laravel, polymorphism, relationship, many-to-one

After getting some help with [Laravel: many-to-many with shared table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923610/laravel-many-to-many-with-shared-table), I wanted to create a "People" table -- an `Employee` **is a** `Person`, but a `Customer` also **is a** `Person` and a `Supplier` **is a** `Person`

However a `Person` can be **both** an `Employee` **and** a `Customer` (why not?)

To address this I decided that:

1. A `Person` hasMany `Role`
2. A `Role` belongsTo `Person`
3. A `Role` morphsTo `personable`
4. An `Employee` morphsOne `personable`

So an `Employee` only points to one `Person` (through `Role`) but a `Person` could have several different `Roles` (`Employee`, `Customer`, etc)

Logically this setup makes sense, but I can't quite figure out what I need to add or change or do in order to actually utilize this model. After some experimentation I found a method for writing, although **I would prefer a more elegant solution**:

```
// Create a new Person and link it to an Employee
$person = new Person(['name' => 'Steven']);
$employee = new Employee(['employee_id' => 1234]);

// Incorrect: person() is a Role, not a Person
$employee->person()->save($person);

// Incorrect: person() is *actually* a Builder and has no method person()
$employee->person()->person()->save($person);

// Throws no errors and seems to work, but it's not very elegant
$role = new Role();
$person->roles()->save($role);
$employee->person()->save($role);

// Desired:
$employee->person()->save($person);

// Also acceptable:
$employee->person = $person;
$employee->is( $person );
```

However **I have not found a good way to read from this model**:

```
// Grab a person
$person = Person::where('name', '=', 'Steven');

// Attempt to find the employee for this person
$employee = $person->roles->.... Employee?
$employee = Employee::where(.... Person =? Role =?
foreach( $person->roles as $role ) { if( $role... is an Employee?
$employee = Employee::whereHas('person', function($q){ $q->where(... person is $person?
```

Reading the Laravel documentation they have good examples and docs for:

- One-to-One
- One-to-Many
- Many-to-Many
- Has-Many-Through (cascading One-to-Many)
- Polymorphic One-to-Many
- Polymorphic Many-to-Many

In the non-polymorphic case the relationship can be simplified by just turning it around. Instead of a `Role` having a `Person` (Many-to-One) you say a `Person` has a `Role` (One-to-Many)

In the polymorphic case, however, there is no "Many-to-One". At first glance it can be simulated with a Polymorphic Many-to-Many and application logic to maintain the "one employee can only have one person" constraint. However reading the docs, a Polymorphic Many-to-Many relationship requires the morphed table to know the types that it can be morphed to:

```
class Person extends Model {

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Employee', 'personable');
    }

    public function customers()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('App\Customer', 'personable');
    }

}
```

This does not scale well as I create new roles for a `Person`.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?

Comment: @AlexanderLomia While I didn't find a good way to do what I was trying to do in this post, I did find a lot of good reasons to not do this. Databases shouldn't map perfectly to ***reality*** ("an employee is a person") but should map to ***your business*** ("we sell to customers, we pay employees"). If there is any shared logic between employees and customers (e.g. each has an "address") then those shared pieces should be separated out into a single polymorphic table ("An Employee has an Address"). If you find yourself saying "is a" in a relationship, you're making your life harder.